# Stereo Headset Volume Different

Tags: sound

I have a headset (HyperX Cloud II), the speaker of the right cup lost sound, after diagnostics, one of the wires that runs between the two cups was faulty (two wires run in the same cord) so I replaced that cord (that runs between the cups), but now the sound is louder in the right cup, would this occur because wire resistance, wire material, or bad soldering?

The cord that I used to replace it was from another headset so it might have a different properties, so would the strand count of the wires effect this, or even strand thickness?

I should also clarify that the original cord had two wires with each several strands coated with enamel then surrounded by insulators surrounded by a fabric on the outside.
The new cord had 5 wires each with several strands with an insulator surrounded by rubber on the outside.
I removed the 3 extra wires within the cord.

I then solder the wires to the correct tabs within the internals of the headset, easy part done, then had to put it back together (a nightmare).

If the issue is resistance could I just figure out a resistor with a certain value, to place in series with the cord, so it lowers the loudness to the correct value? Is that how speakers work with resistors?
Or should I attempt source wires with similar properties to the original, what matters and what does not? (strand count, material, strand thickness, other?)

Thanks for reading and helping.

Comment: if the right side wire failed, then perhaps the left side wire has almost failed

Comment: Chances are, as one of the comments said, the other wire is likely failing. I would say the wire is probably not the problem, but probably the solder joint. I would save yourself the future headache and just replace the wires altogether.

If you insist on measuring the resistance and using resistors to fix the values you can measure the resistance of each wire as you would any other wires (with a multimeter) and then solder resistors accordingly. I highly suggest replacing the wires though or at least fixing the solder joint and checking the remaining wires for quality issues.

Comment: If you can power each side with the same signal and check if they are matched. If so it is the wiring, if not it is the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

What you suggest is **not** the way to fix it.

Headphones typically have a nominal resistance anywhere between 8R and several hundreds of ohms (around 32R is common). Any wire/connector configuration should be much lower (if you measure with a meter you should see around 0.1R or 0.2R, most of which is the meter leads - it's good practice to check first by shorting them together).

The basic idea is that the wires and connectors used to hook things up have MUCH lower resistance than the load (the headphones in this case). It's generally so low that we call it zero. (As the wires are only a few meters and we are at AF we can neglect inductance and capacitance. This remains true unless we are discussing RF circuits which are different animal.)

Once in a very long while you might see a connector or wire which somehow goes high resistance (not open circuit) - like a few hundred or thousand ohms. Usually when this happens it's a solder joint, a dirty connector, or VERY occasionally a PCB track, and the resistance you see is not very stable, so you wouldn't ever try to fix it by adding resistors. The right way is always to find the bad connection and make it almost zero ohms again (clean the connector, resolder the joint).

The presence of 3 or 5 wires in the cable is not a big deal. The overall resistance still is damn close to zero. You don't have to take some cores out because the one you are replacing has a different number. Mostly this is about flexibility.

Yes, those enamel (if that's what the coating is) are hard to solder. Where I could I've often replaced them with ordinary twin-screened cable which is a bit heavier and less flexy but lasts longer and is easily replaced.